# how can i put an Array on another file

Tags: php

(premise I'm new to PHP)
my question was can I put the $ logins array in another file and put something to make the file work anyway?

```
<?php session_start(); 
if(isset($_POST['Submit'])){
$logins = array('Alex' => '123456','username1' => 'password1','username2' => 'password2');

$Username = isset($_POST['Username']) ? $_POST['Username'] : '';
$Password = isset($_POST['Password']) ? $_POST['Password'] : '';

if (isset($logins[$Username]) && $logins[$Username] == $Password){
$_SESSION['UserData']['Username']=$logins[$Username];
header("location:index.php");
exit;
} else {
$msg="<span style='color:red'>Invalid Login Details</span>";
}
}

?>
```

Comment: Are you looking for https://php.net/require ? This would probably be covered in any good intro to PHP, which would be quicker than asking everything here.

Comment: all in `$_SESSION` will be accessible from any page if you add `session_start()` at the beginning of the file. ref. https://www.php.net/session_start

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can put $logins into separate file, like  'logins.php' and include this file in any place you want.

```
    ./logins.php

    <?php
    $logins = array(
               'Alex' => '123456',
               'username1' => 'password1',
               'username2' => 'password2'
               );
```

example:

```
<?php session_start(); 
if(isset($_POST['Submit'])){
require('logins.php');

$Username = isset($_POST['Username']) ? $_POST['Username'] : '';
$Password = isset($_POST['Password']) ? $_POST['Password'] : '';
```

Comment: Thanks a lot man